# HTML/CSS mouse hover image hides

Tags: html, css, hover, image

I have 2 images, 1 shows the word "home" and another shows "home" with some arrows pointing to it from above.. basically a little thing to spice up my website that im working on as part of my studies.

What would be the easiest way to transition from the blank image to the arrow' image?
without using fancy JavaScript? i don't like javascript and would prefer not to use it.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>This is my website :D</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
        <div id="menucontainer">
            <div class="menulink" id="menu1"><a href="index.html"><img border="0" id="arrow1" src="images/arrow1blank.png" /><img border="0" id="arrow1popup" src="images/arrow1.png"  /></a></div>
            <div class="menulink" id="menu2"><a href="#">About Us</a></div>
            <div class="menulink" id="menu3"><a href="#">Services</a></div>
            <div class="menulink" id="menu4"><a href="#">Account</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
#banner {
    background-color:#000000;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    left:350px;
}
#menucontainer {
    position:relative;
    left:750px;
    top:0px;
    right:350px;
    height:100px;
}
#menu1 {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
}
#menu2 {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
}
#menu3 {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
}
#menu4 {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
}
```

Thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this but sprites + css is the best.
Reduces number of requests, requires no reload of image on hover so on slow connections you won't get that 1 second black area while the roll over image loads.

This is popular concept, you will find plenty of tutorials on it like [this one](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-css-menu-using-image-sprites).

Its all about the image :)

Comment: Agree. You can use resources like http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ that generate the images + the css code for you.

Comment: i would rather not generate a code, seeing as that is cheating -.-

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DCrrm/4/ .. i hope you dont get too offended: i used 2 generators for that http://cooltext.com/ for the images and http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ to generate the sprite .. the css is all human-generated .. i think :)

Comment: @Gobble45: The CSS code is very simple in sprite menus. A sprite image essentially has 2 or 3 versions of the menu item (default, hover, active) and the CSS code adds the required pseudo classes needed to display the different parts of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this snippet would work.

```
.menulink:hover { background-img:url('images/arrow1blank.png'); }
.menulink:hover a { display:none; }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesnt hide the original images...
what do i use to hide them to begin with? so i dont have 2 images taking up space..

Comment: Then you have to put display:none of original image at hover, too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.menulink       img#arrow1popup { display: none;   }
.menulink:hover img#arrow1popup { display: inline; }
.menulink:hover img#arrow1      { display: none;   }
```

Comment: Wait, nevermind!!! THAT WORKED.. i had changed the ID's arrow1popup to arrow1, and arrow1 to arrow1blank